# stucked in the post preview component

Tags: reactjs, graphql, gatsby, algolia

I'm stucked, lost... I'm using gatsby-plugin-algolia, when I search, the empty fields are filtered. They are generated by the PostPreview component.

[image]

my archive.js in templates folder (to list blog posts):

```js
imports....

// algolia search
import algoliasearch from 'algoliasearch/lite'
import { InstantSearch, SearchBox, Hits } from 'react-instantsearch-dom'
import PostPreview from '../components/postPreview/PostPreview'

const searchClient = algoliasearch(
  'MY KEY...',
  'MY KEY...'
)

const archiveTemplate = ({
  data: { allWpPost },
  pageContext: { catId, catName, catURI, categories, numPages, currentPage }
}) => {
  return (
    <Layout>
      <Wrapper>
        <BreadCrumbs
          parent={{
            uri: '/blog/todos-os-posts',
            title: 'Blog'
          }}
        />
        <ContentWrapper>
          <ArchiveSidebar catId={catId} categories={categories.edges} />
          <PageContent>
            <InstantSearch searchClient={searchClient} indexName="Gatsby">
              <SearchBox />
              <Hits hitComponent={PostPreview} />
            </InstantSearch>

            <h1 dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: catName }} />
            {allWpPost.edges.map(post => (
              <article key={post.node.id} className="entry-content">
                <StyledDate
                  dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: post.node.date }}
                />
                <Link to={`/blog${post.node.uri}`}>
                  <StyledH2
                    dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: post.node.title }}
                  />
                </Link>
                <p dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: post.node.excerpt }}></p>
                <StyledReadMore to={`/blog${post.node.uri}`}>
                  Leia +
                </StyledReadMore>
                <div className="dot-divider" />
              </article>
            ))}
            <Pagination
              catUri={catURI} // from the context
              page={currentPage}
              totalPages={numPages}
            />
          </PageContent>
        </ContentWrapper>
      </Wrapper>
    </Layout>
  )
}

export default archiveTemplate

export const pageQuery = graphql`
  query($catId: String!, $skip: Int!, $limit: Int!) {
    allWpPost(
      filter: { categories: { nodes: { elemMatch: { id: { eq: $catId } } } } }
      skip: $skip
      limit: $limit
    ) {
      edges {
        node {
          id
          title
          excerpt
          uri
          slug
          date(formatString: "DD, MMMM, YYYY", locale: "pt")
        }
      }
    }
  }
`
```

My Algolia in Gatsby-config.js:

```js
require('dotenv').config({
  path: `.env.${process.env.NODE_ENV}`
})

const AlgoliaBloghQuery = `
{
  allWpPost {
    nodes {
      title
      excerpt
      id
    }
  }
}

`
```

Works:

[image]

My PostPreview component, here I'm lost.

```js
imports...

const Postpreview = ({ id, title, date, excerpt, uri }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <article key={id} className="entry-content">
        <StyledDate dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: date }} />
        <Link to={`/blog${uri}`}>
          <StyledH2 dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: title }} />
        </Link>
        <p dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: excerpt }}></p>
        <StyledReadMore to={`/blog${uri}`}>Leia +</StyledReadMore>
        <div className="dot-divider" />
      </article>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Postpreview
```

I don't know how to get the data to pass to the props, I don't know if the queries are conflicting (archive.js - gatsby-config). Only read more button are rendered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a broad question where multiple things can go wrong, I will try to answer the most common use case but it will need some effort on your side to debug and find the bug(s).

### A few insights before

When dealing with Algolia + Gatsby, you are delegating to Algolia the responsibility of paginating, show/hide/render all certain posts, etc. So the following part, is redundant, should be removed:

```
        {allWpPost.edges.map(post => (
          <article key={post.node.id} className="entry-content">
            <StyledDate
              dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: post.node.date }}
            />
            <Link to={`/blog${post.node.uri}`}>
              <StyledH2
                dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: post.node.title }}
              />
            </Link>
            <p dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: post.node.excerpt }}></p>
            <StyledReadMore to={`/blog${post.node.uri}`}>
              Leia +
            </StyledReadMore>
            <div className="dot-divider" />
          </article>
        ))}
        <Pagination
          catUri={catURI} // from the context
          page={currentPage}
          totalPages={numPages}
        />
```

Algolia will show all posts by default if you are not searching anything (initial state).

Regarding the pagination, you have the [`Pagination`](https://www.algolia.com/doc/guides/building-search-ui/ui-and-ux-patterns/pagination/react/) component from React InstantSearch, so you don't need to worry about it, Algolia handles it for you.

Everything that is related to Algolia's search must be wrapped inside `InstantSearch` component, otherwise, it will never work.

---

Said that, your `Searchbox` needs to refine the Algolia's result and should look like:

```
import React from "react"
import { connectSearchBox } from "react-instantsearch-dom"
import { Search as SearchIcon } from "@styled-icons/fa-solid"

export default connectSearchBox(
  ({ refine, currentRefinement, className, onFocus }) => (
    <form className={className}>
      <input
        className="SearchInput"
        type="text"
        placeholder="Search"
        aria-label="Search"
        onChange={e => refine(e.target.value)}
        value={currentRefinement}
        onFocus={onFocus}
      />
      <SearchIcon className="SearchIcon" />
    </form>
  )
)
```

Be aware of:

```
    onChange={e => refine(e.target.value)}
    value={currentRefinement}
```

Those are key lines and, if anything is not working as expected, try to print the values in a `console.log`.

Here basically you are "connecting" the component to Algolia's API by `connectSearchBox` HOC, which belongs to Algolia; it exposes the current search string as `currentRefinement` and a function for changing it called `refine`.

> I don't know how to get the data to pass to the props, I don't know if
> the queries are conflicting (archive.js - gatsby-config). Only read
> more button are rendered.

The results, are called "hits" and what you are receiving as `props` is a `hit`, so, your `PostPreview` should look like:

```
const Postpreview = ({ hit }) => {
  console.log(hit);
  let { id, title, date, excerpt, uri } = hit;
 return (
    <div>
      <article key={id} className="entry-content">
        <StyledDate dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: date }} />
        <Link to={`/blog${uri}`}>
          <StyledH2 dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: title }} />
        </Link>
        <p dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: excerpt }}></p>
        <StyledReadMore to={`/blog${uri}`}>Leia +</StyledReadMore>
        <div className="dot-divider" />
      </article>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Postpreview
```

If the rest of the components are ok, you will get the `hit` property which will contain all the needed data so you need to destructure it to get the data. Debug as needed, adding as many logs as needed.

You will find a detailed example (could be improved) in [Gatsby's docs](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/adding-search-with-algolia/#displaying-search-results) where the key components are:

```
import { Link } from "gatsby"
import { default as React } from "react"
import {
  connectStateResults,
  Highlight,
  Hits,
  Index,
  Snippet,
  PoweredBy,
} from "react-instantsearch-dom"

const HitCount = connectStateResults(({ searchResults }) => {
  const hitCount = searchResults && searchResults.nbHits

  return hitCount > 0 ? (
    <div className="HitCount">
      {hitCount} result{hitCount !== 1 ? `s` : ``}
    </div>
  ) : null
})

const PageHit = ({ hit }) => (
  <div>
    <Link to={hit.slug}>
      <h4>
        <Highlight attribute="title" hit={hit} tagName="mark" />
      </h4>
    </Link>
    <Snippet attribute="excerpt" hit={hit} tagName="mark" />
  </div>
)

const HitsInIndex = ({ index }) => (
  <Index indexName={index.name}>
    <HitCount />
    <Hits className="Hits" hitComponent={PageHit} />
  </Index>
)

const SearchResult = ({ indices, className }) => (
  <div className={className}>
    {indices.map(index => (
      <HitsInIndex index={index} key={index.name} />
    ))}
    <PoweredBy />
  </div>
)

export default SearchResult
```

Since Algolia supports multiple indices, the `SearchResult` iterates over all indices and displays hits for each of them using the `HitsInIndex` component. It, in turn, relies heavily on the [Hits component from the InstantSearch library](https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-reference/widgets/hits/react/).

The `PageHit` component is responsible for displaying a single page (“hit”) in a search result.

[`connectStateResults`](https://community.algolia.com/react-instantsearch/connectors/connectStateResults.html) wraps components to provide them with details about the current search such as the query, the number of results and timing statistics.

`Highlight` and `Snippet` both display attributes of matching search results to the user. The former renders the full value whereas the latter only shows a snippet. A snippet is the text immediately surrounding the match. The `attribute` property is the name of the key in the Algolia index (as generated by `pageToAlgoliaRecord` in `algolia-queries.js`).

Overall, it seems that your page is rendering the correct amount the `Postpreview` component but is not rendering the correct content because of the destructure of `hit`.

Comment: I love you Ferran ahhahah.The posts are displayed perfectly now. But all posts have this link: http://localhost:8000/blogundefined. I will search to see what is going wrong. Thank you so much!

Comment: I forgot to add date and uri in gatsby-config.js algolia query. Next challenge, to filter by categories.